# Generate a set of hyperplane equations resolvable

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, problem-solving, plane-geometry

I'm looking for a way to generate randomly a set of $N$ hyperplanes equations using the following equation:
$,\sum\limits^{k-1}_{i=0} (a_i\times x_i) = b\text{,  } k\in \mathbb{N/\{0,1\}}$. And $a_i,x_i \in \mathbb{N}$.

In a way, for **any** arrangements of $k$ equations of this set, I've **always** a solution to the linear system.

I've already tried to generate them by defining some rules:

- uniqueness of equations;
- autorize 1 zero in each column;
- forbid the equation with only zero;

  - $\forall i \in \{0,k-1\}, \text{ } a_i = 0$).
- forbid the equation as multiple of other equations:

  - $\forall i \in \{0,k-1\},\text{ }\exists j \in \{0,k-1\}/\{i\}, \text{ }L_i = \delta \times l_j (\text{where }\delta \in \mathbb{N}$).

The algorithm is very gross then I've noticed I needed to also exclude equations as: $L_h = \delta\times L_i + \sigma \times L_j$.
So I've started to model it as a CSP.

If you have any ideas to generate this set of solvable hyperplanes equations or new rules for my CSP I'm very interested !

Thanks you in advance.